# how to fetch the data which has only single entry in a column in the table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

> I have a table named as scholar and it has a column studentid now i
>   want to fetch the data where studentid comes only once, one id can have multiple entry in the studentid column

below is my structure data

[image]

now i want to get studentid = 123 and 154 all data as these came only once

like below is my desired output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

so what will be the query for that please help

Comment: what do you mean by where studentid comes only once. Do mean you mean there are multiple rows with the same student ID?

Comment: Oops that means you have a misdesigned table. It sounds like you have comma separated values in your studentid column and this is not the way it should be stored. Don't waste time on this problem. Get the database design sorted out instead

Comment: Please add table structure with some dummy data and what is your desire output. That would be very helpful for who wants to give answer. Thanks

Comment: please check the updated one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a query like this:

```
SELECT *,count(*) as cnt FROM scholar GROUP BY studentid HAVING cnt = 1
```

But not this is the fastest solution.

Or you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM scholar GROUP BY studentid HAVING count(id) = 1
```